# Redirect users who don't have accounts with devise_cas_authenticable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cas

I'm trying to use the gem [devise_cas_authenticable](https://github.com/nbudin/devise_cas_authenticatable) to link up Devise with a CAS sign-on page, and I have the option `config.cas_create_user = false` to make sure that people sign up for an account specific to this app before signing in through CAS. When a user who hasn't signed up for an account authenticates through CAS successfully, however, they get sent to the URL `/unregistered?username=<CAS ID>`, which is a blank page.

Is there a way to override this route to have it redirect to the sign up page if someone who has not made an account tries signing in first?